# Laravel - Date mutator

Tags: laravel, date, mutators

Trying to make a mutator in Laravel for date but it doesn't work.

This is my example

```
public function getEventEndAttribute($date)
{

    return Carbon::parse($date)->format('d.m.Y H:i')

}
```

For example in my User model i have this mutator that is working perfectly:

```
// convert email address to lowercase
public function getEmailAttribute($value) {
    return strtolower($value);
}
```

So even if a user write an email with uppercase letters in view it will be converted to lowercase....

And i want the same for my date...to convert from MySQL DB format to my local format

This was copied from SO and still doesn't work.
Please help.

Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\UserRequest;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Auth;
use DB;

class UserRequestsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //dd(DB::table('user_requests')->get());
        return view('user-requests.index', ['userRequests' => DB::table('user_requests')->get()]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('user-requests.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //dd($request->event_end);

        $this->validate($request, [
            'event_name' => 'required|max:255',
            'event_start' => 'required|date',
            'event_end' => 'required|date',
        ]);

        $userRequest = new UserRequest();
        $userRequest->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
        $userRequest->event_name = $request->event_name;
        $userRequest->event_start = $request->event_start;
        $userRequest->event_end = $request->event_end;

        $userRequest->save();

        return redirect('requests');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

When i hit my store method i get this error:
[image]

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: No error...i just want to make the date in my local format from database. I get this 2016-10-27 14:51:00 instead of this 27.10.2016 14:51

Comment: How to make sure that i am even calling this mutator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can actually have laravel automatically mutate your dates to a `Carbon` object by adding the dates array to your model:

```
protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'event_end'
];
```

You can then just format it inside your blade template:

```
{{ $myModel->event_end->format('d.m.Y H:i') }}
```

Or you can add the `$dateFormat` property to automcatically convert all dates on this model to your chosen format:

```
 protected $dateFormat = 'd.m.Y H:i';
```

See date mutators: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Comment: Can you tell me how this protected $dateFormat = 'd.m.Y H:i'; works....in laravel documentation there is no examples....i tried to put that property but the date stil has DB format

Comment: yes like this:     protected $dates = ['event_start', 'event_end'];

    protected $dateFormat = 'd.m.Y H:i';

Comment: If you `dd();` the `event_end` field inside your controller is it a `Carbon` object?

Comment: NO it's a string "27.10.2016 14:51" like from datepicker field

Comment: Yes it should be, can you post your `controller` method?

Comment: I will add it to my question up

Comment: As I suspected, you are using the query builder to get your information which bypasses the model, if you want your `mutators` to take effect you need to make sure you are using `eloquent`: `UserRequests::all()`;

Comment: ok how can i get all the user requests but only from that user....i tried this and it doesn't work: UserRequest::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)

Comment: Flagging this answer as the best : the date in the database should be a valid datetime, no need to store something exotic. The altered date should only display on the template.

Comment: yes all is fine now....i just don't know how to make query for userRequests with eloquent....why this doesn't work? UserRequest::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)

Comment: How to use `eloquent` is another issue, but the best way is to set up your `relationships` on your model and then call that `relationship`. However, for your example I think you are just missing the `get()`: `UserRequest::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get()`

Answer (score 1):

You can try Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat($format, $input). As for the parse method, you can use it to create a Carbon instance from a string.